# Save other ID in database

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 table here :

```
 1. tblPurItem : 

    itemID, categoryID, purchaseMeasurementID, stockMeasurementID, calculationMeasurementID, retailrecipeID

 2. tblRecipe :

    recipeID, recipeName, recipeType

*retailRecipeID = recipeID
```

How do I get the value retailRecipeID in tblPurItem? Because if I add like `(SELECT D.recipeName FROM tblPosRecipe D WHERE A.retailRecipeID = D.recipeID LIMIT 1)` AS recipeName , recipeName is null which is there is no data. I have to get the retailRecipeID because in this situation, I have form. Form 1 is tblPurItem and form 2 is tblRecipe. The form 1 have no problem but form 2 have problem.

When I success to submit the form 1, the form 2 will be popup on radiobutton= yes so that form 2 success to submit data. Now, my problem is data form 2 will be lost because do not link with form 1. And retailRecipeID also null in database. Anyone know the solution? Thank you!

It should be when I open back the form 1 and form 2 the data will displayed back but it show blank not the previous data.

[image: pic1]

> SQL

```
SELECT A.itemID, A.categoryID, A.purchaseMeasurementID, A.stockMeasurementID, A.calculationMeasurementID, A.itemName, A.itemDescription, A.itemPrice, A.lastPrice, A.averagePrice, A.itemType, A.purchaseStatus, A.cutStock, A.chargeOut, A.retailItem, A.consignment, A.marginConsignment, A.active
        , (SELECT B.itemCategoryName FROM tblPurItemCategory B WHERE A.categoryID = B.itemcategoryID LIMIT 1) AS itemCategoryName
        , (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.purchaseMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS purchasemeasurementName
        , (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.stockMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS stockmeasurementName
        , (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.calculationMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS calculationmeasurementName
        FROM tblPurItem A
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Okay, I will update more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `left join` for `tblRecipe`  and `coalesce()` function to get value `0` in your presentation layer in case of no matching recipe

```
select
    coalesce(t2.recipeID, 0) as recipeID
    , t1.itemID
    , t1.categoryID
    , t1.purchaseMeasurementID
    , t1.stockMeasurementID
    , t1.calculationMeasurementID
    , t1.itemName
    , t1.itemDescription
    , t1.itemPrice
    , t1.lastPrice
    , t1.averagePrice
    , t1.itemType
    , t1.purchaseStatus
    , t1.cutStock
    , t1.chargeOut
    , t1.retailItem
    , t1.consignment
    , t1.marginConsignment
    , t1.active
    , (SELECT B.itemCategoryName FROM tblPurItemCategory B WHERE t1.categoryID = B.itemcategoryID LIMIT 1) AS itemCategoryName
    , (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE t1.purchaseMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS purchasemeasurementName
    , (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE t1.stockMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS stockmeasurementName
    , (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE t1.calculationMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS calculationmeasurementName
from tblPurItem t1
left join tblRecipe t2 on t1.retailrecipeID = t2.recipeID
```

Comment: I got error run this in my database : 

Query: select , coalesce(t2.recipeID, 0) as recipeID , t1.itemID , t1.categoryID , t1.purchaseMeasurementID , t1.stockMeasurementID , t...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' coalesce(t2.recipeID, 0) as recipeID
    , t1.itemID
    , t1.categoryID
   ' at line 2

Comment: @Alphabet, try a gain, typo

Comment: Its fine now, but may I know why using coalesce? Just to add my knowledge here

Comment: we are using left join, so there's a possibility that you will be getting null values, coalesce will give you 0 in case recipeID is null

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you so much!